# Testing rxjs pipe operator in constructor

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs, jasmine

I have class to handle the user/auth operations from firestore. The service works correctly but when I try to add test to the service if fails with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined`

This is my service

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`user/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and this is part my spec file for that class

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: FireAutStub },
        { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: FirestoreStub }
      ],
      imports: [AngularFireModule, AngularFireAuthModule]
    })
  );

  it('AuthService should be created', () => {
    const service: AuthService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

any ideas of why the testing is throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined` or do you have any suggestions to test it better o make the service more "testable"?

**Edit**:
here's the the FireAutStub

```
const FireAutStub = {
  collection: (name: string) => ({
    doc: (_id: string) => ({
      valueChanges: () => new BehaviorSubject({ foo: 'bar' }),
      set: (_d: any) => new Promise((resolve, _reject) => resolve())
    })
  })
};
```

and you can see both classes here https://gist.github.com/danielnv18/bfc5940f0bf078c77d895b5c34bf8a27

Comment: Use `OnInit` instead of doing stuff in the constructor. Otherwise, I guess your stubs don't work well and `afAuth.authState` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Please share the source code for your `FireAutStub` class.

Comment: if AuthService is indeed injectable there is no ngOnInit hook for it. Still plz share afAuth class code

Comment: adding a `OnInit` wont some the problem. According to https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks works with Directives and Components only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mocking `FireAuthStub` incorrectly. It expects an `authState` property.

Try setting it to:

```
 const FireAutStub = {
   authState: new BehaviourSubject(true),
 }
```

Now to mock `authState` to true and false for subsequent tests to hit the `if` or the `else` might be tricky. You might have to associate it to some type of subject where you can do `.next` on it and control its value.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I trying to learn more testing with angular